# PHP - Get unique value from 2 strings

Tags: php

I work on a script to detect the root value in order to properly redirect with header location and I need to obtain the webroot value.

```
define('abspath', __DIR__ . '/');
$a = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$b = str_replace('\\', '/', abspath); // windows
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

Output:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs

C:/xampp/htdocs/site/
```

I'm looking to somehow obtain the value `$c = "/site/"` from both strings.

Comment: `$c = substr($b, strlen($a));`

Comment: You can't obtain `/site/` if it doesn't exist in the path.

Comment: You're doing this already: `$b = str_replace('\\', '/', abspath);`, so just continue string_replacing your way to success with the variables you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that your file paths will always be absolute, then you can use:

```
$c = substr($b, strlen($a));
```

If you're using relative paths then you can use:

```
$c = substr($b, (strpos($b, $a) + strlen($a) - 1));
```

More about [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)